# "Index was out of range exception" error

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to find the first missing positive integers in an array and i keep on getting this error message. I'm quite new to programming and i can't figure out the reason for this. Can anyone help me find the problem?
Also, when the input is [1], it also throws an exception.

This is my code:

```
public static int solution(int[] A)
{
    Array.Sort(A);
    List<int> missing = new List<int>();
    List<int> An = new List<int>();

    foreach (var r in A)
    {
        if (r > 0)
        {
            An.Add(r);
        }

    }
    int lengthList = (An[An.Count]) - (An[0]);

    for (int i = An[0]; i <= lengthList - 1; i++)
    {
        if (An[i + 1] != An[i] + 1)
        {
            missing.Add(An[i] + 1);
            An.Insert(i + 1, An[i] + 1);
        }
    }
    if (missing != null)
    {
        return missing[0];
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add also input array?

Comment: What is *missing positive integer*, please?

Comment: `(An[An.count])` should be changed to `(An[An.count-1])`. Arrays are zero based, but `count` will return the amount of elements in `An` which will be one based

Comment: You lengthList  should be `int lengthList = An.Count;`

Comment: Your problem is in this line. int lengthList = (An[An.Count]) - (An[0]); . It would be An.Count-1. the index of an array is starting at zero. So if you have Count=1 it will be at index 0

Comment: `if (missing != null)` will always be `true` (since you've created the instance with `List <int> missing = new List <int> ();`); so when `missing` doesn't have items you'll get the exception on `return missing[0];`

Comment: If you had used a debugger you wouldn't have posted the question. The best answer is always _next time use the debugger_

Answer (score 3):

You have several flaws in your code. The most important is

```
 int lengthList = (An[An.Count]) - (An[0]);
```

What should should that be? The length of `An` - the number of items in `An` you can iterate over - is given by `An.Count`.

And since lists are 0-indexed, your index `i` should walk from `0` (*not `An[0]`*) to `An.Count-1`. So your code should look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < An.Count; i++) {
    if (An[i + 1] != An[i] + 1) {
       missing.Add(An[i] + 1);
       An.Insert(i + 1, An[i] + 1); // this will break your algorithm
}
```

`i<An.Count` avoids accessing the index after the last item.

Note that this only fixes this `IndexOutOfRangeException`. I don't know if the algorithm does what you want at all. You *insert* elements to `An` *while iterating* over it (line `An.Insert...`). This seems wrong to me.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm a real beginner and i can't figure out how to do this. How do i get the lowest missing positive integer? I tried so many ways and nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @yehudisgrosz Sorry, but this is not a code writing service. Keep trying and you'll figure it out. And by finding out by yourself you will learn more than by copying code from the internet. And as others suggested: use a debugger to go through your code step by step and see what goes wrong and why.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a off-by-one error:

In your `for` loop you use this exit condition:

```
i <= lengthList - 1
```

ON a list with for example 10 items that would iterate until 9.

Then you access the array like this:

```
An[i + 1]
```

In the given example you would access An[10] which does not exist in a 10-item array/list.

Your correct exit statement for the loop is:

```
i < lengthList - 1
```

Yur calculation of `lengthList` seems to be also wrong. Change it to:

```
int lengthList = An.Count;
```

Your initial code

```
int lengthList = An[An.Count] - An[0];
```

...gives you also an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. It also makes no sense. You are accessing the *content* of the list, not its *length*.

**Sidenote:**

Your inital loop condition

```
int i = An[0]
```

...is probably also wrong. Did you mean this?

```
int i = 0
```

Comment: The only problem is the fact that the variable _lengthList_ is totally wrong. It doesn't measure the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

your problem code:

1) (An[An.Count]) fix that: An[An.Count-1]

2) int lengthList = (An[An.Count]) - (An[0]); fix that: int lengthList = An.Count;